# MZInAppLockerAccessException (status 21010) Apple verifyReceipt endpoint exception in-app-purchase subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, receipt-validation, in-app-purchase-receipt

I am working with subscription in-app purchases and am hitting the following endpoint with stored receipts: https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Just this past weekend (starting 10/24/2020) I started to get the following exception returned and can no longer verify my receipts, a critical part of my business.

```
{
    "exception": "com.apple.jingle.commercelogic.inapplocker.exception.MZInAppLockerAccessException",
    "environment": "Production",
    "is_retryable": false,
    "status": 21010
}
```

Why did I just start seeing these now, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you calling the endpoint from your app or at backend?

Comment: @StefanWang This is being called from the backend, so purely hitting the https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt endpoint with an existing receipt, and getting this response.

Comment: 21010 status is a very rare case. 
According to developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/status , it indicates token expiration or something like user authentication fail.

Comment: @StefanWang I see the documentation says "The user account cannot be found or has been deleted", but where do you see it is a rare case? Is there other documentation? Thanks for the help

Comment: *rare case* - Based on my experience. And didn't meet that status at all in my past projects (10+ backends with IAP)

Comment: According to RevenueCat, 21010 errors should be treaded as stated: "This receipt could not be authorized. Treat this the same as if a purchase was never made." I have gone ahead and marked the subscription as inactive for product purposes.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Users with no IAP history have no receipt. So, it will be correct.